# How to use ModelCheckpoint() in Keras with weighted validation loss

Tags: keras

I train a DNN in Keras which has high imbalanced classes. So I used class_weight in fit_generator to correct this. Now I want to save the model with the lowest weighted validation loss using the ModelCheckpoint() function. I am trying but I can't figure out the way to achieve this. Would any one have a simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ModelCheckpoint("checkpoint.hdf5", monitor='val_loss', mode = 'min', verbose=1, save_best_only = True)
model.fit_genetor(....)
```

I think you are asking for this piece of code.

Comment: Not exactly. I want the model to be saved when  the **weighted** val loss as a metric is in the lower value. Because the validation data is unbalanced.

Comment: Instead of giving (x_validation,y_validation) tuple to as validation data, you can give (x_validation, y_validation, weights)


now you've given your weights , 'val_loss' will be weighted loss.

https://keras.io/models/model/

Comment: Thanks, that is what i was looking for!

Comment: Is this possible also with validation generator as parameter on validation data ?

Comment: Yes. yield(x,y,w)